# emacs: package-name is an available obsolete package

Tags: emacs, package, melpa

Whenever I install a MELPA package, I get this message:

> package-name is an available obsolete package

Here is a screenshot of what I mean (first line):

[image]

I tried [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/665724/why-all-emacs-packages-can-suddenly-become-unsigned-and-obsolete) but it did not help.

How to fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Since I started to use GNU Emacs 26.3, I do not face this issue.

Comment: weird. That's actually the version I have installed now

Comment: When you removed the previous version, are you sure you did not forget to delete its related settings, for example in **.emacs** file ?

Comment: deleted everything. But it's not a huge problem. I can install packages, it's just that as soon as they're installed, the heading above changes to 'available obsolete from melpa'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That message confused me too. It turns out it's just a poor choice of words for saying that there's a new version available.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2019-02/msg00082.html

Once you update the list of packages with `M-x package-refresh-contents`, then you can type `U x` and it will upgrade all installed packages that have a more recent version available.

Once that is done, the message you see when you open the description of an updated package will be:

> Package x is installed.